# Maven: Downloading a jar with unconventional name

Tags: maven-2

I am trying to download http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.1 in my POM. However, the actual jar is named json-lib-2.1-jdk15.jar. Maven is looking for the artifact name + version, hence json-lib-2.1.jar. So, it's not being found. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
  <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
  <type>jar</type>

</dependency>
```

Comment: `<type>jar</type>` is optional there.